# Black eyes when model Imported

Tags: transparency

For some reason when I import this model, its eyes are fully blacked out. I tried to recalculate and flip the eyes but nothing happens. I got the model from steam and imported it to blender if that information helps.

[image]

This is what its supposed to look like

[image]

Comment: It seems like you’re a novice. I strongly suggest you do not try importing game models right now, as that is a whole can of uniquely textured and rigged worms that you do not want to deal with yet, trust me. Speaking of which, this is probably a materials issue, just possibly one with blend set to no alpha when it should be alpha hashed, but more likely a texture is hooked up wrong because of incorrect auto-setup.

Comment: As TheLabCat says it's probably a problem of transparency, hard to say without the file, you can share it here: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures